# css li menu dynamic line widths in IE6

Tags: html, css, menu, internet-explorer-6

I've got a css menu like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Item1</a></li>
  <li><a>Item Two</a></li>
  <li><a>Item C</a></li>
  <li><a>A Rather Long Menu Item Down Here</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to create this:

```
|-----------------------------------|
| Item1                             |
|-----------------------------------|
| Item Two                          |
|-----------------------------------|
| Item C                            |
|-----------------------------------|
| A Rather Long Menu Item Down Here |
|-----------------------------------|
```

but I'm getting this:

```
 -------- 
| Item1 |
|----------- 
| Item Two |
|-----------
| Item C |
|----------------------------------- 
| A Rather Long Menu Item Down Here |
 -----------------------------------
```

If I set either the [li] or [a] tags to display:block, they stretch to fill the maximum possible width. I want them all to have the same width, which is dynamically determined by the widest item, rather than by manually putting a width on the [ul] tag.

Oh, and the target is IE6. :)

#### Update:

`width:1px, overflow:visible` didn't work. (Got the same squashed effect as without the display:blocked anchors.)

This is for an intranet where IE6 is the target, so I'm stuck there. (In other projects, I've stopped worrying about it.) JS is a requirement, so maybe I'll use that. (I always hate doing that, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only option is javascript.

BTW, one of my sites is visited by a large amount of home users.  We've seen that IE6 is down to 12% of our traffic.  Two months ago it was 20%.  This is while overall IE traffic is staying at 76%

My point is that you probably shouldn't worry about IE6 quirks too much anymore.

Comment: I would advise against the use of JS to solve this, although it is of course an option. Far simpler CSS only solutions exist. And I'm afraid the time when one can stop worrying about IE6 quirks is not quite here yet; 12% of visitors is far too high to ignore!

Comment: @ola: The ROI for the time to figure out how to correct a truly minor display quirk for 12% (and falling) of your users is extremely low.  It's much better to invest your time in adding functionality or fixing bigger issues.

Comment: Almost two years have passed and IE6 usage is down to 2.71% - when it drops below 1% maybe we can finally move on...

Comment: @Ola Tuvesson: For us it has dropped to 1.74%.  ;)  Totals are: IE 64% (most of which on 8 and 9), Firefox 13%, Safari 13%, and Chrome 7.5%.  Covers about 60,000 home users.

Answer (score 6):

This is remarkably simple:

```
<style>
ul {
float: left;
}
    ul li a {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    }
</style>

<ul>
  <li><a>Item1</a></li>
  <li><a>Item Two</a></li>
  <li><a>Item C</a></li>
  <li><a>A Rather Long Menu Item Down Here</a></li>
</ul>
```

The trick here is the combination of floating the <ul> and adding white-space: nowrap; to the blocked anchors. In fact you don't even need the "nowrap" unless your <ul> is battling for space. As for the suggestion of ignoring 12% of your visitors.. well...

Comment: Up vote for your code, down vote for your arrogant statement "This is remarkably simple".

Comment: The only arrogant statement in this thread was the suggestion that 12% of users somehow didn't count. Lazy *and* arrogant. And yes, the solution is remarkably simple. Thanks for your (non) vote!

Comment: You sir, are a genius for coming up with such a simple solution. This has fixed an issue I had where IE6 was reporting that an unordered list (and therefore all its parents as well) was much narrower before it was shown to the user than after. [..and simple doesn't necessarily imply that it was easy]

Answer (score 1):

Certain amount of hacking to make it work in IE6, because width:auto never really worked properly.

I have seen some solutions to this problem using width:1px; overflow:visible;, which might work in this case, but best to do it in a conditional comment so as not to stuff up in "real" browsers, or use the holly hack or similar. Be aware that IE 6 will probably handle this differently in quirks mode to standards mode, so know your doctype.

BTW, would put your anchor tags as block, so you get consistent width mouse targets.

Answer (score 1):

To get shrinkwrapped *li* inside the *ul* with pure CSS but uneven widths try:

```
ul,li {float:left;}
ul {overflow:hidden;}
li {clear:left;}
```

(then maybe adapt *[faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)* with fixed line-height and a repeating background image to style the *li* elements)

If you're *sure* it's IE-only then JavaScript can be built-in to CSS with a *[dynamic property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634.aspx)* to set the child width to match the parent thus:

```
ul,li {float:left;}
ul {overflow:hidden;}
li {clear:left;width:expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth);}
```